# Mysql one row from reference table then mutiple rows in joined table

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to produce something like this result in MySQL join statements?

```
ID  |  Name  | profile_ID | Detail_ID | Details
 1  |  John  |     1      |   uuidj1  | detail1
null|  null  |     1      |   uuidj2  | detail2
null|  null  |     1      |   uuidj3  | detail3
 2  |   Doe  |     2      |   uuidd1  | detail1
null|  null  |     2      |   uuidd2  | detail2
 3  |   Foo  |     3      |   uuidf1  | detail1
 4  |   bar  |     4      |   uuidf2  | detail1
```

I've produce a by row data for each detail with this sql statement.

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Name, a.ID as profile_ID, b.Detail_ID, b.Details
FROM profile as a
LEFT JOIN details as b on b.profile_id = a.id
```

Comment: You could also use RIGHT instead of LEFT, but because we (people in general) tend to find LEFT more intuitive, it's more common to simply switch the order of the joins

Comment: a.id is still a.id; profile_id is an alias. So when joining b.profile_id to the aliased column, you would still use `b.profile_id = a.id`. For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: updated a.id sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN a.ID = LAG(a.id) OVER (ORDER BY a.ID, b.Detail_ID) 
            THEN NULL
            ELSE a.id 
            END AS ID,
       CASE WHEN a.ID = LAG(a.id) OVER (ORDER BY a.ID, b.Detail_ID) 
            THEN NULL
            ELSE a.Name 
            END AS Name, 
       a.id profile_ID,
       b.Detail_ID, 
       b.Details
FROM profile as a
LEFT JOIN details as b on b.profile_id = a.id
ORDER BY a.ID, b.Detail_ID
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ceaa25a8b979f730c7ee0125988bb30a

Comment: wow thanks, i didn't know what is LAG and OVER do and its new to me, anyway thanks!